# How to generate a Rest API from SOAP Backend with WSO2 AM version 4.0?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I registered the API with Publisher through the method below.

https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api/create-rest-api/generate-rest-api-from-soap-backend/

So the API list was automatically created,
[image]

After verifying, I get an error message like the one below.
What part do I need to edit? Please help me.

[image]

Comment: This feature is now deprecated and it is recommended to use MI and Integration Studio for such complex conversions. Anyway from the provided screenshots, cannot figure out the exact cause. The conversion logic in runtime is inside the Resource page of the API in publisher portal. You may need to add log mediators and debug it.

Answer (score 0):

When you provide the WSDL file, it generates an REST API for the given WSDL. For each API resource path, it generates a Synapse mediation sequence. This mediation sequence is used to create the SOAP request.

When a REST API request comes to the API Gateway, the Synapse engine inside the gateway uses these mediation sequence in each API resource path and create the SOAP request. Then this SOAP request is sent to the relevant backend service. You can edit these sequences as specified in the step 6 in [1].

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/create-api/create-rest-api/generate-rest-api-from-soap-backend/